# Selenium Standalone + NightwatchJS Mail Errors

Tags: email, selenium, nightwatch.js

Is there an Option to send Mails with Nightwatch/Selenium when some of the tests fail? I am missing that option the most in the documentation of Nighwatch.

Since it has to be automated, you do not want it to run on your local machine. Instead using it on a Vserver.

Any ideas what to look up or if I can realize it without using Java?

Comment: If you are using a CI system for running tests then the CI server can be configured to set out emails in case, the tests fails it will result in a failed build

To send out emails you will probably have to setup scripts in python or related language

Comment: I am also trying to solve this problem.  I don't need a full CI server.  I just need to run some e2e tests on a schedule and email any errors.  If you find anything let me know.